Does using older google mobile ads package affect earnings in flutter
I rebuild my app in flutter and I couldn’t use the latest google_mobile_ads package since it is incompatible with webview_flutter: ^2.0.13 package. And so as suggested by Android Studio, I had to settle for google_mobile_ads: ^2.4.0 instead of google_mobile_ads: ^5.0.0.
I then updated the app but now my match rate dropped to 70% and daily earnings dropped by 90%.
Summary: Rebuilt my app in flutter and integrated older google_mobile_ads package with hoping to get better earnings but the opposite happened

Why do you downgrade your google_mobile_ads sdk in the first place? The reason for the google_mobile_ads upgrades is to correct error.
Since you have your match rate at 70% and earnings down to 90%, I think the best thing for you is to reverse to previous google_mobile_ads: ^5.0.0
